# _plugins_vuetify__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_136__.default is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

I have build a vue app with `vue cli 3` and added vuetify.
Now to reduce my bundle size I changed the vuetify import to:

I am using `vuetify 1.5.5` and `vue 3.7.0`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify, { VLayout, VBtn, VApp } from 'vuetify/lib';
import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl';

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  components: {
    VApp,
    VLayout,
    VBtn,
  },
  theme: {
    primary: '#ee44aa',
    secondary: '#424242',
    accent: '#82B1FF',
    error: '#FF5252',
    info: '#2196F3',
    success: '#4CAF50',
    warning: '#FFC107',
  },
  options: {
    customProperties: true,
  },
  iconfont: 'md',
});

export default Vuetify;
```

But after this I get this error in console:
[image]

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue which starts happening immediately after getting this error ```Failed to resolve loader: stylus-loader
You may need to install it.``` I then went and installed stylus-loader with ```npm install --save-dev stylus stylus-loader webpack
```  Then I got the error in the console which we're facing now. Did you also have this issue?  It could be importing to fixing this.

Comment: I solved my problem. Do you on version 2 from vuetify?

Comment: I'm on version 1.5.0. Unfortunately, I can't upgrade from 1.5 to 2 because breaks everything but it should be noted somewhere that upgrading to version 2 fixes the problem if you don't mind upgrading all your components according to the version 2 documentation (which i do).

Comment: version 2 is better, and it is normal that the components will break because there are many improvements on v2.

Comment: Yeah, definitely version 2 is better it's just a pain migrating from 1.5 to version 2. I guess now I know how it feels to be an angular developer.

Comment: yep it will take some times to do, but it's useful

Comment: Why do you export `export default Vuetify;`, are you using it somewhere?

Comment: You must be instantiating Vuetify elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

summary: you shouldn't write export default Vuetify;
vuetify.js is just a js file you should import in main.js

```
// plugins/vuetify.js


import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl'
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
iconfont: 'md',
  theme: {

primary: colors.green.base, // #4CAF50

secondary: colors.red.lighten4, // #FFCDD2

accent: colors.indigo.base, // #3F51B5

search: colors.grey.lighten2, // #E0E0E0

searchButton: colors.green.lighten3,  // #A5D6A7

newsBlock: colors.grey.lighten4, // #F5F5F5

// info: colors.lighten1,

// warning: colors.darken2,

// error: colors.accent4,

// success: colors.lighten2,

  }
})


// main.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/vuetify'
...
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
})
```

Comment: That is not the issue. My guess is that the OP was exporting Vuetify and instantiating it elsewhere. As you can see, the error refers to OP trying to use Vuetify as a constructor.